# How can I patch the User model while keeping existing data?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-1.7

I have a big Django application, currently trying to upgrade from 1.6 to 1.7 (there's been attempts to upgrade straight to 1.11, but it was too much trouble, so my plan is to do it one minor at a time).

I'm following the [Upgrade from South](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south) instructions, and deleted all previous migrations, but I can't get `makemigrations` to work. The current problem is that the `auth.User` model has been patched to include two new fields:

```
User.add_to_class('profile',
                  models.ForeignKey('access.Profile', null=True, blank=True,
                                    related_name='user_foreignkey'))
User.add_to_class('profiles', 
                  models.ManyToManyField('access.Profile', null=True,
                                         blank=True))
```

This patch was made in a separate app. If I just leave it where it is, I get the following error when running `python manage.py makemigrations`:

```
ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field auth.User.profiles:
access.Profiles
```

I tried moving the `add_to_class` calls to the same file where `Profile` is defined, (after the definition), but got the same error. I also tried changing the syntax from `'access.Profile'` to `Profile`, to no effect. Is there something else that could make this work?

If not, since I'm adding fields to the model, I figure the correct approach would be extend the AbstractUser model, as suggested by [this guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractuser). The problem with this is that the new initial migration will create a table `access_user` instead of using the existing `auth_user`. Would it be safe to simply rename `auth_user` to `access_user` and fake the migration?

Any other suggestions on how to overcome this with the least refactoring possible (management always thinks there are more urgent things than the upgrade) are welcome.

Comment: it's not recommended to remove migrations files unless you know what you do, or reinitiate your project entirely (database included)

Comment: @Lemayzeur Removing the migrations (the files, not from the database) was part of the [Update from South](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

tl, dr; I removed `auth` migrations and ran `makemigrations` again, that seems to have solved the problem.

I had decided to give option 2 a try. I removed the `add_to_class` patches, created a new `class User(AbstractUser)` with the new fields, removed all the existing migrations and ran `makemigrations` again. I got the exact same error, which made no sense because there was no longer any code relating `auth.User` to `Profile`, so I decided to investigate `auth` migrations. I ran

```
$ python migrate --list settings=settings.mysettings
```

and it showed a suspicious migration for `auth`, with yesterday's date, probably when I first tried to make migrations.

Tutorials on "how to reset all migrations" do not mention third-party installed apps, but thanks to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/m59NufO1GI8) I knew where Django stored the auth migrations, so I removed both of them (the initial and the suspicious one) and reordered the `INSTALLED_APPS` so that `access` is now before `django.contrib.auth`. Then ran `makemigrations` again, and it got through `access` and `auth` migrations successfully.

I'm now getting other problems with migrations in other apps, but they don't seem to be related with this.

It might be nice to have a more intuitive way to reset all existing migrations, not only those from your repo. But then again, I don't think the `add_to_class` patches are the proper way to do what we wanted.